# Phusion-passenger compiles extension for wrong ruby when using RVM

Tags: ruby, rvm, passenger

I have set up RVM system-wide with Ruby 1.9.2 and as far as I can tell, it works fine.

But when I try to compile Passenger apache2 module via

```
passenger-install-apache2-module
```

It compiles it for system's 1.8.7 (the `ext/ruby` folder contains `ruby-1.8.7-x86_64-linux`) and when I start apache, the Passenger complains:

```
*** Phusion Passenger: no passenger_native_support.so found for the current Ruby interpreter. Compiling one...
# mkdir -p /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/passenger-3.0.7/ext/ruby/ruby-1.9.2-x86_64-linux
```

But the problem is that Apache runs on read-only filesystem, thus Passenger fails to compile the module at runtime. What do I need to do to get it to compile it beforehand for Ruby 1.9.2?

I've even removed original `/usr/bin/ruby18` binary and then it ends in error:

```
Compiling and installing Apache 2 module...
cd /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/passenger-3.0.7
/usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.2-p180/rake apache2:clean apache2 RELEASE=yes
# /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.2-p180/rake apache2:clean apache2 RELEASE=yes
/usr/bin/env: ruby18: No such file or directory
```

PS. I have read few similar questions here, but none seem to apply directly. The file `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/passenger-install-apache2-module` has correct she-bang row for `...1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby`.

**EDIT:** Added more info

Apache Passenger conf is:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/passenger-3.0.7/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/passenger-3.0.7
PassengerRuby /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby
PassengerLogLevel 3
PassengerDebugLogFile /tmp/passenger.log
```

And just in case it is helpful I post `rvm info` output.

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180:

  system:
    uname:       "Linux aevastaja 2.6.31-gentoo-r6 #2 SMP Wed Jan 6 19:40:30 EET 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 4.1.9(2)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)"
    zsh:         " => not installed"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.6.18 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]"

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "1.9.2p180"
    date:         "2011-02-18"
    platform:     "x86_64-linux"
    patchlevel:   "2011-02-18 revision 30909"
    full_version: "ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-linux]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180"
    ruby:         "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/bin:/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc-bin/4.4.5"
    GEM_HOME:     "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180"
    GEM_PATH:     "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180"
    IRBRC:        "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that apparently while installing newer Rake gem, I had had the environment wrong and though the gem ended up in RVM under 1.9.2, it actually referenced system 1.8.7 binary and that Passenger install script ran this rake, which in turn built the module against wrong ruby.

Helped to uninstall and reinstall Rake gem.

Answer (score 7):

If you use different ruby-version for different ites, you may only need the native-support and can just run `passenger-config build-native-support` after switching to the right ruby-version.

Use `passenger-config build-native-support --help` to see for which ruby-version the command will build the native support.

Comment: A good tip. Though, as that is only the very latest 4.0.42 (released two days ago) that introduces that command, I can't accept thit as an answer.

Comment: Wow. Just had a similar problem on an Ubuntu-server yesterday and wasn't aware of the fact it is _that_ new.

Answer (score 2):

For others with this issue, please note that Passenger may be taking cues from a config file (e.g., `/etc/httpd/conf.d/passenger.conf`) other than your primary Apache config file.

Comment: Yes, I found the PassengerRuby in there was wrong.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I typically install Passenger under the `global` gemset and then create a wrapper for it.  The following [guide](http://everydayrails.com/2010/09/13/rvm-project-gemsets.html) shows each step.

Answer (score 1):

Years late to the party, I know, but here's what fixed it for me:

After running passenger-install-apache2-module for both Ruby 1.8.7 and 2.0.0, I ended up with passenger_native_support.so in:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/passenger-4.0.5/libout/ruby/ruby-1.8.7-x86_64-linux/passenger_native_support.so
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/passenger-4.0.5/libout/ruby/ruby-2.0.0-x86_64-linux/passenger_native_support.so
```

I had PassengerDefaultRuby set to a 2.0.0 wrapper, and for a particular virtual host, PassengerRuby set to a 1.8.7 wrapper.  The 1.8.7 app would not start because Passenger didn't know where to look for the 1.8.7 version of passenger_native_support.so and had no write access to compile a new one.

Two options to fix this:  1.)  Set a new directory with PASSENGER_NATIVE_SUPPORT_OUTPUT_DIR that it did have access to write to, or 2.) symlink the 1.8.7 output dir to the 2.0.0 output dir, e.g.

```
$ ls -l /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/passenger-4.0.5/libout/ruby
  ruby-1.8.7-x86_64-linux -> /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/passenger-4.0.5/libout/ruby/ruby-1.8.7-x86_64-linux
  ruby-2.0.0-x86_64-linux
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you switched your Ruby *before* running the passenger install?

```
rvm use 1.9.2
```

You can check your current Ruby (and gemset, etc) with:

```
rvm info
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but yes, I have switched ruby. (And I have run the installer with explicitly naming ruby binary `...1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby $(which passenger-install-apache2-module)` and even `rvm 1.9.2 exec passenger....` and the combination of both). I've simply run out of ideas to try.

Comment: OK, weird that it's not working then. Would be useful to see your apache configuration for passenger.

Answer (score 0):

Will need to set the "**GEM_HOME**" variable.

Add this to your passenger config file (eg: `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/passenger.conf`):

```
SetEnv GEM_HOME /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1
```

Of course, change this "*ruby-2.3.1*" with your actual version.

---

A more extensive example:

```
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
  SetEnv GEM_HOME /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1
  PassengerRoot /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini
  PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/bin/passenger_free_ruby
</IfModule>
```